# Standard/Specification for regular alkaline batteries

Tags: batteries, alkaline

Where can one find the standard specification for regular alkaline AAA, AA, C and D batteries? I mean, I know that different suppliers must have different battery capacity/property but there must be some standard that regulates this market. Eg.: maximum allowed current, minimum energy capacity, etc.

Comment: As I understand it the various sizes are just various size. There is no requirement for current or energy capacity. The only things that are set are the voltage level and the physical size.

Comment: @AndyHall So how can one decide if an electrical design should be supplied by one AAA or one AA battery since both have the same voltage? What design parameter is used to pick up the right battery size?

Comment: In my experience, space for the battery and "normal" battery capacity is what we go by. But if you look into it, you'll see that many C and D batteries have the same capacity as AAs , often they're just AAs in larger boxes (as mentioned on wikipedia).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where can one find the standard specification for regular alkaline AAA, AA, C and D batteries?

The international standard is IEC 60086, specifically:
[IEC 60086-2:2015 - Primary batteries - Part 2: Physical and electrical specifications](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/23621)
(current cost is CHF 250)

`Abstract:
IEC 60086-2:2015 is applicable to primary batteries based on standardized electrochemical systems. It specifies the physical dimensions, the discharge test conditions and discharge performance requirements. [...]`

Examples of IEC battery type designations include:

- alkaline AA = LR6
- alkaline AAA = LR03

Other [IEC battery designations are given in the Wikipedia article on battery sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battery_sizes).

(I believe there is an ANSI-equivalent to this IEC standard, but I haven't used it.)